# Can you match sub-fields with $all in Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-query

I have a collection of document, where each document looks like this:

```
{'name' : 'John', 'locations' : 
   [
     {'place' : 'Paris',  'been' : true}
     {'place' : 'Moscow', 'been' : false}
     {'place' : 'Berlin', 'been' : true}
   ]
}
```

Where the locations array could have any length.

I want to match documents where the `been` field is true for all elements in the `locations` array. [Looking at the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/) it looks like I should use [$and](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/all/) somehow but I'm not sure if it works with sub-fields.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options:

- use $ne: `db.destinations.find({"locations.been":{$ne:false}})`
- change your business logic to precompute that value before saving the document. Otherwise, this search must look through all records and then all places. This value could be indexed.
- use the $where operator, but, understand the [performance](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/where/#_S_where) implications. It may require a full table scan. In this case, it would.
- write a [map-reduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/map-reduce/) function with the filter logic and only emit those that are valid. You'd need to incrementally update it per the docs.
- write a query using the [aggregation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-examples/) framework. There are a lot of good examples [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-aggregation-comparison/). Although, like other solutions, this could end up looping through the entire collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's impossible to do with standart MongoDB operators like `$elemMatch` or `$all`. The only possible way is to write custom JS query:

```
db.test.find("return this.locations.every(function(loc){return loc.been});")
```